# Как центрировать текст по вертикали в UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift

У меня есть UILabel, размер текста которого автоматически подбирается с учётом доступной ширины:

```
label.adjustsFontForContentSizeCategory = true
label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
```

На Layout этот UILabel имеет 4 constraint'a:
Центр по X и Y; отступы слева и справа.

Если вводить короткий текст, то текст в UILabel находится посередине (x = y):

[image]

Если ввести длинный, то текст "уходит вниз" (размер шрифта автоматически уменьшается, расстояние от верхней границы UILabel до текста увеличивается). При этом, высота самого UILabel не меняется.

[image]

Как всё-таки центрировать текст по вертикали?

Answer (score 0):

Измените baseLine этой UILabel:

```
label.baselineAdjustment = .alignCenters
```